# Display custom facets in Sitecore Experience Profile version 9 or later

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-profile, contact-facets, speak

I am creating custom facet for saving contact information (Like Car Model, Variant, Color, etc) into XDB. I am successfully able to save and retrieve custom facets details with respective Contact. Now I am trying to show that custom facet on Experience Profile.
To do the same I have followed below articles:

1) http://zhenyuan.azurewebsites.net/post/displaying-custom-facets-in-contact-profile

2) http://reyrahadian.com/2016/08/28/sitecore-8-extending-experience-profile-part-3-displaying-contact-facet-collection-property/

3) https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/using-custom-contact-data-part-1-experience-profile

4) https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/

**What I have done to show Custom facet on Experience Profile:**

1) Created web API for retrieving the custom facet.

2) Register API in route

3) Created physical folder in application `/Sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/CustomTab`

4) Created Custom CSS in core DB and associated it with server location CSS(Deployed CSS in root path)

5) I am using Sitecore Rocks extension as well to customize tab.

**Issues I am facing:**

1) How to create a custom tab in core DB? (I am creating a duplicate of existing Tab then it's showing new custom tab but existing functionality are not working and replaced with new custom tab)

2) How to associate Speak.Js(use Speak.Js to do the same) with custom tab and controller and display custom facet data?

I am implementing its using `Speak JS`.

Answer (score 9):

I do this using [Experience Profile Express Tab](https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/EPExpressTab) code. It allows you to add a custom tab to the contact in experience profile. Then you just load your facet into it.

You can put anything in the model. In the code below I am pushing 3 different facets into it. What the code does is looks for any model that is inheriting from the class `EpExpressViewModel`. If it finds it, it adds a tab in experience profile.

#### Build a model

```
public class MemberView : EpExpressViewModel
{
    public override string Heading => "My Tab";
    public override string TabLabel => "Membership";
    public override object GetModel(Guid contactId)
    {
        var contact = EPRepository.GetContact(contactId, MembershipFacet.DefaultFacetKey, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey);
        var memberData = contact.GetFacet<MembershipFacet>(MembershipFacet.DefaultFacetKey);
        var personalInfo = contact.GetFacet<PersonalInformation>(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey);

        return new MemberInfoModel
        {
            ContactId = contact.Id.ToString(),
            VisitCount = 4,
            MemberDataIsNull = memberData == null,
            PersonalInfoIsNull = personalInfo == null,
            MemberData = memberData,
            PersonalInfo = personalInfo
        };
    }
    public override string GetFullViewPath(object model)
    {
        return "/views/MembershipXdb/MemberInfo.cshtml";
    }
}
```

#### Make a view

In the view `/views/MembershipXdb/MemberInfo.cshtml` you can add the HTML from a normal speak panel. It's like getting the look of speak with none of the effort.

When it is done, mine looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to do the same with Speak.JS. Is there any idea/article which describes how to do it with Speak.JS.

Comment: Here is how I did originally way back. I think it would still work in 9. It is pretty basic. https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/using-custom-contact-data-part-1-experience-profile

Comment: Thanks, Chrics for the suggestion, but unfortunately no success yet. Below issues I am facing:

1) How to create a custom tab in core DB? (We are creating a duplicate of existing Tab then it's showing new custom tab but existing functionality are not working and replaced with new custom tab)

2) How to associate Speak.Js with custom tab and controller and display custom facet data?

Comment: We did custom facet tab for Experience profile as you need with SPEAK and Sitecore Rocks for Sitecore 9.0. I hope this article can be helpful for you https://www.konabos.com/blog/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-in-sitecore-9. You can also see our example here https://github.com/Sitecore-Hackathon/2018-Sitecore-Friends/tree/master/documentation. To associate custom tab with backend code you should add your  custom pipeline into <group groupName="ExperienceProfileContactViews"> section.

Comment: Thanks, @x3mxray, Have seen your article. I am working the same as you did, but unfortunately I am not able to get Contact on bases of contactId. I have raised question for the same, could you please guide or help me.

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/get-xdb-sitecore-analytics-tracking-contact-with-contact-id-always-returning-nul

Comment: Hi, @HimmatSinghDulawat, I answered to your issue about null contact. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/get-xdb-sitecore-analytics-tracking-contact-with-contact-id-always-returning-nul