# Display Custom Facet in Sitecore Experience Profile 9.1.1

Tags: xconnect, experience-profile, contact-facets

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1,

I Followed this [Link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-facet.html) to create a custom facet to each contact and its added successfully to xDB, I don't have a screenshot of it but its like the below image:

[image]

and this is my JSON file if it would help

```
  {
  "Name": "AccountModel",
  "Version": "0.1",
  "References": [
    {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model",
      "Version": "9.0"
    }
  ],
  "Types": {
    "project.Models.AccountInformation": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "project.Models.AccountInformation, project, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "username": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "formattedName": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "honorificPrefix": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "entitlements": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "x509Certificates": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "schemas": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "id": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "externalId": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "employeeNumber": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "costCenter": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "isDeleted": {
          "Type": "Boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Target": "Contact",
      "Name": "AccountInformation",
      "Type": "project.Models.AccountInformation"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I tried to do next is create a custom tab in Experience Profile similar to "Details" tab and add the values of this Custom Facets, I followed the following links: [first](https://www.konabos.com/blog/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-in-sitecore-9), [second](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/scott-mulligan/posts/sitecore-amp-salesforce-another-approach-to-extending-experience-profile-in-sitecore-9), [third](https://xcentium.com/blog/2018/12/19/view-custom-facets-values-from-within-sitecore-experience-profile) and many others.

The part where I get stuck in is when I suppose to add the fields, I don't know where to get the Ids added in the DataSource facets like in the "Details" tab in below photo:

[image]

am I suppose to add my custom facets to core database and take the Ids of them and if so how can I connect them with my JSON file and the xDB field.

or am doing it wrong. I don't know I got pretty lost in this part can you please advice me.

Comment: I don't want to take you off your path, but I just wrote this so you can see there is an easier way. https://www.waitingimpatiently.com/add-facet-to-experience-profile-the-lazy-way/

Comment: You should have a look at the [EP Express Tab](https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/EPExpressTab) as @ChrisAuer mentions in his blog post. We use it for all of our project and it makes it really easy to add an additional tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These datasource IDs are just ids of common UI controls like Text or AdvancedExpander that are used to render corresponding blocks for tab (there items are children items of tab-item *(or items from /sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Common/System/Texts)*.

[image]

Here is a good article about how to create custom tab in SPEAK for Experience Profile https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/comment-page-1/.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and raised it on Sitecore StackExchange.

[Display custom facets in Sitecore Experience Profile version 9 or later](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18198/display-custom-facets-in-sitecore-experience-profile-version-9-or-later)

The part where you stuck is a `core database` part. You need to perform all the operation in the core database, but for that, you have to use `Sitecore Rocks`.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JakobChristensen.SitecoreRocks

After that, you can create renderings and assign/get Ids.

Follow the below article, it helps me lot to create rendering and ids.

https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2016/04/19/extending-sitecore-experience-profile-speak-app/